# jQuery UI dialog buttons without all the default classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating a jQuery UI dialog programmatically, as in

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        buttons: [
            {
                class: "myButton",
                text: "Ok",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

When the dialog is created, however, the button has a list of default classes assigned to it, and the label s wrapped in a SPAN.

```
<button type="button" class="myButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
     <span class="ui-button-text">Ok</span>
 </button>
```

I'd rather the button just have `myClass`, period, and if possible no `span`. As in:

```
 <button type="button" class="myButton">Ok</button>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Don't use jquery ui. Do your own css. Edit: I meant don't create the buttons using jquery dialog and add your own buttons.

Comment: That's how jQuery UI works, it uses all those classes internally. If they interfere with your application, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 400,
  open: function(){
    $(this).next().find("button").removeClass("ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget");
  },
  buttons: [
    {
      class: "myButton",
      text: "Ok",
      click: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    },
    {
      text: "Cancel",
      click: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

"create" function can be used instead of "open" function

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 easy ways to accomplish this: (just use one of the following)

1 Just create the button as an html string in your code:

EX: `$("#someelem").html("<button type=\"button\" id=\"myid\" class=\"myclass\">Ok</button>");`

2 Download jQuery UI non-compressed and change the code so that the output is just the class you pass and does not add a span to the html.

EX FROM jQuery UI Code:

```
var buttonElement = this.buttonElement.removeClass( typeClasses ),
            buttonText = $( "<span></span>", this.document[0] )
                .addClass( "ui-button-text" )
                .html( this.options.label )
                .appendTo( buttonElement.empty() )
                .text(),
            icons = this.options.icons,
            multipleIcons = icons.primary && icons.secondary,
            buttonClasses = [];
```

Just remove the span tags so that buttonText = this.options.label; or something similar.

3 Change the class and button html with JavaScript after creation.
EX: `$(".myButton").attr("class","myButton").html("Ok");`

Comment: Good approaches.  I'll see which works best, thanks.